# Is it possible to "OR" search criteria?

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to specify a search whose results list is the union of two other searches?

Comment: Some information regarding tag searches is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags)

Comment: That's very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `OR` searches on tags. For example, `[linear-algebra] [or] [real-analysis]` [returns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra+or+real-analysis) questions tagged with at least one of the two tags.

It doesn't look like the search engine here supports the `OR` operator for text keywords. You can use Google for this:

```
convergence OR matrix site:math.stackexchange.com
```

([results](https://www.google.com/search?q=convergence%20OR%20matrix%20site:math.stackexchange.com))